# All dates that i enter to my Firestore database is getting + 1 hour. (Google Firestore and datestamp problem)

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Why does Firebase add one hour to the value when adding to a timestamp?

I have a python script that put some values into a colllection in a Firestore database. The data includes a timestamp. (See python code here:)

```
def insertIntoFirebase(yrRow):

    #myDate = dateutil.parser.parse(yrRow.fromDate) 
    myDate = datetime.strptime(yrRow.fromDate, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    print("Tiden " + str(myDate))
    doc_ref = db.collection('yrData').document(str(yrRow.index))
    doc_ref.set({'index':yrRow.index ,"timeText": yrRow.fromDate,'time': myDate, 
   'temperature':yrRow.temperature})
```

In this method i put some values into the firestore collection YrData. Look at the KeyValue pair time and timeText

When looking in the Firestore database the value for the keyvalue pair **time** is 2020-01-16T23:00:00 witch is the correct datetime and what i want to store to the database. This is stored as a string in the firestore database.  The problem is the keyvaluepair **timeText** witch is stored as a Firebase Timestamp. (See screenshot)

When looking at the Firestore for the keyvalue pair **time** the value is not what i put into the datbase. It is my value + 1 hour. (See screenshot)

When getting the dates from the Firestore documents in Swift, it is also one hour added to the timestamp. :(

The server running the python script, my computer running the browser and my MacBook running the swift code have all the same timezone.

Edit: changed some mistakes and added the last paragraph about timezone

[image]

Comment: Timezone on my linux server running the python script
pi@rpi:~ $ date +"%Z %z"
CET +0100

Timezone on my Macbook: (Running the browser and swift iphone project)
Jimmys-air-2:~ jimmybergetun$ date +"%Z %z"
CET +0100

Answer (score 1):

Your code is formatting `timeText` according to the timezone configured on machine that's formatting the date (maybe UTC?).  The Firestore console formats timestamps according to the timezone of the machine running the browser (UTC+1).  These are apparently different timezones, different from each other by 1 hour.  This is a common misunderstanding - it comes up a lot on Stack Overflow.

Note that a Timestamp object doesn't contain any timezone information.  It is just an offset from unix epoch time.  In order to format a human-readable time from it, a timezone needs to be assumed, which is where you run into apparent differences in time.

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to help. I see that i messed  up when i asked the question. The key value “timeText” (string in firestore) has the correct value , but when I store the same value as Date (datestamp) in firestore in the time key value pair, one hour is added. :-(.  The server running the python script, my computer running the browser and my MacBook running the swift code have all the same timezone.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.  Python doesnt really care what timezone your are on and have a "strange" implementation of timezone generally. To fix this issue i had to make python aware of the wanted timezone . (Even though it is set on the server running the script). The code bellow fixes my issue.

```
    myDate = datetime.strptime(yrRow.fromDate, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Oslo')
    aware_datetime = tz.localize(myDate
```